# Moore neighborhood of range r?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

The group of cells with a [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) ≤ *r* are called the [von Neumann neighborhood of range *r*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood#von_Neumann_neighborhood_of_range_r). What is the correct term for the corresponding [Moore neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood), i.e. the cells with a [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) ≤ *r* ?

Answer (score 1):

Range seems to be the correct term here as well. This Wolfram article uses exactly that terminology: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MooreNeighborhood.html.